# solr delta import "fetches" but does not "process"

Tags: mysql, solr, dataimporthandler

when I run /solr/dataimport?command=full-import it processes all the documents. However, when I run a delta import (/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import) it correctly identifies the updated data (returns "`<str name="Total Rows Fetched">1</str>`") but does not process any of it (returns "`<str name="Total Changed Documents">0</str>`")

my data-config.xml looks something like this:

```
<entity name="category" pk="catID" 
query="SELECT CONCAT('c_',catID) ID, catID, catName FROM category" 
deltaImportQuery="SELECT CONCAT('c_',catID) ID, catID, catName FROM category WHERE catID = '{$dataimporter.delta.catID}'" 
deltaQuery="SELECT catID FROM category WHERE catDate &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"/>
```

(note - there is a seperate reason for my concat)

why does the full import process while the delta import fetches but does not process?

Comment: What do you mean by "but does not process any of it"?  Perhaps you just need to issue an explicit solr `commit` command?

Comment: I mean that solr does not get updated - period. why does full-import get committed automatically and delta-import does not? by the way, running the command /solr/dataimport?command=delta-import&commit=true still does not work...

Comment: By which you mean you don't see the new documents in the index?  Is that still true even after you force a `commit` operation?

Comment: yes. no documents are added. how do I force a commit? (see my previous comment)

Comment: Please post Solr's **log** and **response** message that shows your delta-import.

Comment: Did you guys ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Is your `DataImportHandler last_index_time` updated after the `delta-import`?

Comment: sorry for the delay; @Andrew Kozak - where would I find this 'last_index_time'? it is not one of the pieces of info I am shown when I enter '/solr/dataimport/' after the delta-import

Comment: @Atomox - sorry not yet. In the meantime I am eaking by with a cronjob doing full imports - which is okay for the time being as there is still little information.

Comment: [This](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Delta-Import_Example) may help you.

Comment: @AndrewKozak thanks, but I was using that documentation originally and followed it to the word, but it did not help for this issue

Comment: Have you tried removing the `CONCAT()` from your `SELECT`?  I'm shooting from the hip here, but it could be some column name issues or something else that's polluting the query.  I know @Atomox resolved his similar problem, so hopefully he'll be able to weigh in.

Comment: In my experience, when it was not posting, it was a config issue with the primary key. Meaning, I didn't type in the proper key. You should not have to explicitly request a commit on a full import or a delta, in my experience.

Answer (score 5):

`'{$dataimporter.delta.catID}'`, here the `catID` should be the value of the name attribute in the field definitions. I had same problem, then realized that the referenced variable is the field name... I hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and figured out that deltaImportQuery is case sensitive

Made my id Column as "ID"

deltaImportQuery="select id,state,name,place,city from temp where **ID='${dih.delta.ID}**

Answer (score 0):

This is because a full-import will process every document in your database.

A delta-import only processes documents that have been modified since your last import of any kind (in your case, dictated by the catDate field).

For example, suppose you do a full-import at 2012-09-09 12:15:38.

Next, you do a delta-import at 2012-09-10 12:15:38. Only documents that have a catDate > '2012-09-09 12:15:38' will be processed.

The idea is that delta-import is a way to maintain an ever changing index without having to do a full-import each time.

Comment: thank you. but the problem was that the delta import was not importing anything at all

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the delta query works fine but your delta-import query fails.

This is because you have given,

deltaImportQuery="SELECT CONCAT('c_',catID) ID, catID, catName FROM category WHERE catID = **'{$dataimporter.delta.catID}'**"

But it should be given as,

deltaImportQuery="SELECT CONCAT('c_',catID) ID, catID, catName FROM category WHERE catID = **'${dataimporter.delta.catID}'**"